# What are the default direcories in which changes are done when a program is installed in windows

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

Want to know all the Directories that are Created /Modified when we run a new setup and install any program on windows.

I know some of them Being %Temp%, Appdata, %windir%\installer, Registry, Program Files. But is Confused about the exact paths and significance

Can some one please tell the exact paths, where all data is kept/modified, why the step is done and what is the significance of that move. Also please advise the same about the registry.

Comment: An install could change any number of directories on the system, and create new ones too. It's like asking what directories will be changed when you run a program - it depends on what's in the program. Same with the registry. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually I want to create my own installer and Uninstaller. So, want to know all the places where my files are kept. Like When we go to Add remove programs and select Change on a program, Windows automatically pulls up the setup from somewhere( from backup which it has created) and runs it even if we do not have the original setup file on PC. As I want to create a complete uninstaller and Installer so want to know all locations where by default changes are made in windows. Custom and Program Specific locations I know as I am myself making the installer.

Comment: Your files are "kept" where you choose to install them, same with the registry entries. There is no created backup, just indo in the registry and directories like \Windows\installer. You don't need to worry about any of this just to create an installer - it's all automatic.

Comment: I need to know as I want to make the Uninstaller too, and don't want to leave any trace of my application on host

Comment: That happens automatically too. I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. All the files installed by an MSI are removed by default. Just build the setup and then address any specific problems if in fact there are any.